# looping a php script to insert data for multiple users

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables: **phpbb_sn_fms_groups** and **phpbb_fms_user_groups**, which I would like to INSERT into using the two queries below, however the first problem is I can't possibly manually run the two queries ~1000 times for each user_id (56 through 1060). The second problem is I need to INSERT the auto incremented fms_gid from the first query (table: phpbb_sn_fms_groups) into fms_id from the second query (table: phpbb_sn_fms_users_group) when the php script INSERTs each user_id.

```
// user_id: 56 through 1060

// fms_gid in the table phpbb_sn_fms_users_group needs the unique fms_gid for each row from the table phpbb_sn_fms_groups because it doesn't autoincrement.

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO phpbb_sn_fms_groups (fms_gid, user_id, fms_name, fms_clean, fms_collapse) VALUES ('autoincrementednumberthatdoesntneedtobeinserted', '56', 'Staff', 'staff', '0')")
or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO phpbb_sn_fms_users_group (fms_gid, user_id, owner_id) VALUES ('inserttheautoincrementednumberfromfms_gidinphpbb_sn_fms_groups', '2', '56')")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great time for PDO.
See http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php for connection info but something like

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

// First select the users you need query.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id BETWEEN 56 AND 1060");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

OR if literally 56 through 1060 you can use a for loop.

Then loop through those results to execute

```
foreach($result as $row) {

    $stmt1 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO phpbb_sn_fms_groups (fms_gid, user_id, fms_name, fms_clean, fms_collapse) VALUES ('autoincrementednumberthatdoesntneedtobeinserted', :user_id , 'Staff', 'staff', '0')");
    $stmt1->bindParam(":user_id", $row['id']);
    $stmt1->execute();

    //get last inserted id.
    $inserted_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

    $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO phpbb_sn_fms_users_group (fms_gid, user_id, owner_id) VALUES (:last_id, '2', :user_id)");
    $stmt2->bindParam(":last_id", $inserted_id);
    $stmt2->bindParam(":user_id", $row['id']);
    $stmt2->execute();

}
```

Hope this gets you started. Can also be done in mysqli. Don't want to jump into that debate. I just like naming the parameters for binding.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Seems like I need to learn about PDO asap.

Comment: PDO is pretty easy to get going with and the code ends up looking a lot easier to read. Here's a [quick introduction to PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

Comment: Thanks I'll start looking it over now. It's never fun relearning syntax.

Comment: Took a bit for me also coming from mysql() but found I like it. Probably even yet a better way is to pull the 2 prepare statements out of the foreach loop. Here is an example http://hastuts.com/insert-multiple-rows-in-one-query-using-pdo-mysql-prepared-statements/